# Why am I losing data after I perform asfreq

Tags: pandas, frequency

So I got a data set of approximative 6000 cells in my excel. In the objective to determine some patterns I would ike to define that this dataset is a minutely frequently one but after a asfreq('T') I lose a big part of my datatset why ?[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfLnx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is filling in `NaN` for the rows that you don't have values for. If you do `.head(10)` you'll see that your original values are still there

Comment: Thanks I found the error. It was coming about the fact taht all my dataset wasn't at the same seconds of records. After changing my timestamps it's good now